# How to provide MySQL my.cnf after S2I has run

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

In the [Red Hat Software Collections MySQL container](https://github.com/sclorg/mysql-container/blob/0fac1d4a616f7facf71e77f8c06b8827561a2b83/5.7/README.md), I see that you can set `MYSQL_DEFAULTS_FILE` to indicate the path to a completely different `my.cnf` file. When used in OpenShift, I don't understand how to get such a config file on disk, since their S2I scripts have already been run as part of the `mysql-persistent` template. How do I go about injecting such a file into a pre-built image?

I'm able to deploy MySQL 5.7 using the template provided with OpenShift, and can set other environment variables, but am not sure how to put *my own* files into the image so I can reference them.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to store arbitrary config data (`my.cnf` sections and values) in a ConfigMap, mount that ConfigMap as a file using `volumes`/`volumeMounts` in the `mysql-persistent` DeploymentConfig, then adjust the `MYSQL_DEFAULTS_FILE` environment variable to point MySQL at the newly mounted config file. Here's a guide that describes how to do that for Redis:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/configuration/configure-redis-using-configmap/